# Calendário em Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Gostaria de criar um calendário em Rails 4. Segui alguns tutoriais na internet, porém, não obtive sucesso. Consegui fazer através do table_builder o calendário no formato "por mês" porém, preciso muito mais da visualização semanal (com as horas do lado esquerdo e os dias em cima). Não consegui pensar em uma forma de criar isto.

Tentei utilizar algumas gems, como event-calendar ou simple calendar, mas não consegui fazer funcionar corretamente com rails 4.

Também fui atrás de alguns códigos em JavaScript e/ou HTML, mas não sei se é a forma ideal, pois aí o 'filtro' seria feito no lado do cliente (client-side) e aí iria trazer todos os registros dos eventos de uma só vez, sobrecarregando o client (creio eu).

Se alguém puder me ajudar com esta questão, fico no aguardo.

Comment: Tente isso:
https://github.com/bokmann/fullcalendar-rails Essa gem já gera o html e os JS que são necessários!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode criar uma ação no controlador que usa um parâmetro de data (dia atual, por exemplo) e filtra a query para a semana dada, por exemplo:

```
def eventos_da_semana
  semana = params[:data_da_semana_desejada].at_beginning_of_week
  @eventos = Event.where("data_inicial > ? AND data_inicial < ?", semana, semana.next_week)
end
```

Na view é só iterar pelos eventos por dia e por hora (use scopes ou métodos no model ou então no cliente mesmo)